# pip says to upgrade while already updated

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, environment

while using pip I often has the message:

```
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 22.2.2 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`
```

However when I do :`pip -V`, `python -m pip -V` `py -m pip -V`, all returns me

`pip 24.0 from C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)`

and when I do `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`

I have this:

```
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Using cached pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-24.0
[notice] A new release of pip is available: 22.2.2 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`
```

So it looks like I have the latest version but it doesn't recognize it.

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: `python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip` suggests that you might not be using the same python in both cases. What does `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` output?

Comment: It returns me exactly the same as above for full path\python.exe -m, python -m and py -m

Comment: Try `python -m pip cache purge` and then run the upgrade command again.

Comment: Now I have different lines but the result is still the same: ```Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Downloading pip-24.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
   ---------------------------------------- 2.1/2.1 MB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-24.0

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 22.2.2 -> 24.0
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip```

Comment: What's interesting is that pip show pip gives me 22.2.2 which is different from pip -V that gives me 24.0.


pip show pip:
Version: 22.2.2
Location: c:\python310\lib\site-packages


pip -V:
pip 24.0 from C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I had multiple .dist-info files in pip location folder.

Keeping only only the last one and deleting the others solved the issue